# what things do I need to do to get an app ready for 'production' environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

I decided to test my app in the production environment today. It's running fine in test and dev environments. But when I started a mongrel server in production I got a message about assets not being available so I did:

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Well that got the app booting up but now my images and css are all resolving to 404s. So I think there must be a checklist of things to do to get a Rails 3 app ready for production. I googled a bit but didn't see anything like "make sure you check/do all these things before you switch to prod".

My command to start the server: `rails s -e production -p 5000` (because I want to run the prod/test/dev mongrels on the same server right now).

So, what do you do when you switch an app from `test` to `production`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your webserver you may have to change the following setting in config/environments/prodcution.rb from:

config.serve_static_assets = false
To:

config.serve_static_assets = true